# Какое событие отвечает за постоянную проверку PasswordBox и TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне надо сделать так, что бы кнопка была не рабочей на странице до тех пор, пока все текст боксы и пасворды не будут заполнены.

Сам код вод, но какое событие вызвать, понять не могу.

```
if ((Login.Text.Length == 0 && Password.Password.Length == 0) ||
            Password.Password.Length == 0 || Login.Text.Length == 0)
            {

            BtnVxod.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
            BtnVxod.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Научитесь использовать WPF по назначение, научитесь делать привязки и поймите что такое команды, которые как раз и имеют `CanExecute`, позволяющие без труда сделать кнопку неактивной, пока не будет выполнена определенная логика.

Comment: решение в лоб - создайте метод `CheckEnter()`, в него поместите код, который все проверяет и меняет `BtnVxod.IsEnabled = true` или `false`, и вызывайте этот метод из каждого обработчика события `TextChanged` для каждого текстбокса. Но вы ерундой занимаетесь, надо учиться использовать привязки `Binding` и команды на базе `ICommand`, они такие штуки поддерживают нативно (`CanExecute`).